# How can I install the license key for my Abee CHM Maker?

Tags: chm

I had to reformat and have no instructions for installing the licence.key file after installing Abee CHM Maker. Their website has no help for it and no response from their support.

I have work to complete, so I am hoping to hear from another licensed user.

How do I install the licence.key file to activate the software?

Comment: Did you check the old email after purchasing with the license key to see if it contains information? What's about using Abee CHM Maker with nag screens (free version)? Have you tried to copy the license.key file into the same folder where the exe resides? Sorry, I'm not using CHM Maker yet.

Comment: Maybe useful: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.portablefreeware.com/forums/viewtopic.php%3Ft%3D23516&ved=2ahUKEwjKuIzbn8rfAhUCfFAKHbPxBK4QFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw0PNK_NHOWNQAynzX8dbfMb&cshid=1546265694554

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this puzzle is found by opening the licence.key file in Notepad to produce...

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AbeeTech\CHM Maker]
"Name"="Your Name"
"Key"="ABCD-EFGH-IJKL"
```

Those are instructions to follow, ie: Regedit > create key as described.